# get second element by class name if it exists

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the ID of an element by class name like this

```
var prod_id2 = document.getElementsByClassName('select-selected')[1].id
document.getElementById('hidden-input-2').value = prod_id2;
```

This works fine, but my issue is that if there's only one element with that class it breaks the functionality, so I need some sort of if statement to only define this var if there is a second div with that class.
Any ideas?

Comment: Get the node list and verify that `.length` is at least 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

if (elements[1]) {
  elements[1].innerText = 'Hithere';
}
```

```html
<div class="test">hi</div>
<div class="test">hi</div>
<div class="test">hi</div>
```

1. `document.querySelectorAll('.test');` selects all elements with the class test and returns a nodelist.
2. Then we can access the second element via of the **nodelist** with elements[1].

Answer (score 0):

It breaks the functionality I think because you are grabbing the 2nd element specifically. You can do:

```
const prod_id2 = document.querySelectorAll('.select-selected');
```

and loop over the elements and grab the ID

```
prod_id2.forEach((prod, index) => {
 if(index === 2) {
  document.getElementById('hidden-input-2').value = prod.id;
 }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to check for the second element.

You can also set another fallback , different to null:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var selectedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.selected-selected'),
    prod_id2 = selectedElements[1] || null;
  alert(prod_id2)
});
```

```html
<div id="test" class="selected-selected"></div>
```

You can also check that value then:

```
if (prod_id2) { // do some other stuff with the set value }
```